# What to do when there is a jargon that is the same with a common word?

Tags: topic-model

Let's say in a particular field, the word `the` has a specific meaning and not just be a determination. The common `the` one and the specific `the` one are use mixedly in the corpus. Is there a way to handle this? Or manually tagging the specific ones before pre-processing is the only option?

I've looked at the question [Detect if word is «common English» word or slang word](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/64136/119882) but it doesn't seem to answer this.